# Celery Task Not Registered Exception in Python 3.7, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, redis, celery, task-queue, celery-task

This is how the celery configuration looks like

```
from celery import Celery, group


celery = Celery('grouptest', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')


celery.conf.CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'      
celery.conf.CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER ='pickle'     
celery.conf.CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = {'json', 'pickle'}


@celery.task
def add(self, x,y):
    print('Executing with arguments', x, y)
    return x+y
```

I am starting the celery worker daemon with the command (in the same working directory)

```
$celery worker -A grouptest -l info -c 5
```

in the terminal.

Next, from another process, I am calling the service like this.

```
bigList=[(randint(60, 90), randint(60, 90)) for _ in range(10)]
jobresult=group([add.s(celery, i[0], i[1]) for i in bigList]).apply_async()
#Basically adding a ten pairs of random numbers
```

The funny thing is, only some of the tasks are executed, even after long wait. For example, `jobresult[0].result` gives the sum of two numbers just fine, but `jobresult[1].result` says `Task of kind 'grouptest.add' never registered, please make sure it's imported.`

I am even checking if `jobresult.ready()` is set `True` in the python REPL. Sometimes it throws error, sometimes it does not, in the same REPL session. (After some observation, I guessed, it passes from `False` to error to `True`.)

I am new to celery and following some templates, but how to make sure I the task is properly *registered* (whatever that means) and *all* of them are executed consistently. If my code was wrong, at least the errors would be consistent, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Celery does not support Python 3.7 at the moment this comment is being written.
You might be able to use a workaround:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4500